# Authenticating Twitter on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-oauth, spree

I'm using the twitter gem along with amniauth to fetch a user's tweets and display them on my homepage. But when I try to grab tweets from the command line I'm getting a 'bad authentication data' error.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'twitter'
```

Twitter.rb in config/initializers:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'key'
  config.consumer_secret = 'secret'
  config.oauth_token = 'token'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'secret'
end
```

omniauth.rb in config/initializers:

```
require 'omniauth-twitter'
config.omniauth :twitter, 'key', 'secret'
```

I've double checked my key and passwords, but I can't get it to run. I am using Spree. Here's the error:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'twitter'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Twitter.user_timeline(213747670)            
Twitter::Error::BadRequest: Bad Authentication data
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter/response/raise_error.rb:21:in `on_complete'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:9:in `block in call'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:63:in `on_complete'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:13:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter/request/multipart_with_file.rb:14:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:247:in `run_request'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:100:in `get'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter/client.rb:81:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter/client.rb:64:in `get'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter/api/utils.rb:51:in `objects_from_response'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter/api/utils.rb:42:in `objects_from_response_with_user'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter/api/timelines.rb:53:in `user_timeline'
    from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter.rb:52:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):2
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch and display user's tweets its better to go with *twitter* gem.
Refer the following links for step-by-step instructions

http://shouweick.blogspot.in/2011/11/rails-3-and-twitter-api-by-shouweick.html?showComment=1381925399790#c6571680143535387130

https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550